# Failed to reload and display data in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, crud

Firstly, I'm a beginner in Swift and iOS development. This is my first app, which I am working on after learning the basics of Swift and iOS.

Reloading the data in the `tableview` after adding new data is working properly using Realm. Unfortunately, after an update or deletion, reloading the data in the `tableview` does not work. Showing the previous data in table view after an update or deletion. Please help.

**How the code works or app works:**

1. Home page ***HomeViewController*** contains an empty list of data in table view and a button called ADD.
2. ADD pressed --> jump to add page, having field for title and notes --> DONE pressed --> return to home, reload and display the title in the Data.(This is working)
3. Using `didSelectRowAt` it jumps to the ***DisplayDataViewController***, just to view the title and notes in the Data. This page contains EDIT and DELETE button.
4. EDIT pressed --> jump to edit page ie ***AddNotesViewController*** (same page is used for add and edit, that's why I used flagAdd/flagEdit variables) --> after update it goes to home page, and it should be reloaded and display (reloading fails here, no changes in `tableview`).
5. DELETE pressed --> goes home, unfortunately reloading fails here also.

And the thing is, CRUD is working properly with the database.

**Data**

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

@objcMembers class Data: Object {
    dynamic var title = ""
    dynamic var notes = ""
}
```

**HomeViewController:**

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, RefreshDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableViewField: UITableView!
    
    let realm = try! Realm()
    
    var taskView: Results<Data>?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableViewField.delegate = self
        tableViewField.dataSource = self
        loadData()
        
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let addVc = segue.destination as! AddNotesViewController
        addVc.flagAdd = 0
        addVc.delegate = self
    }

    func loadData() {
        
        taskView = realm.objects(Data.self)
        tableViewField.reloadData()
        
    }

}




extension HomeViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return taskView?.count ?? 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = taskView?[indexPath.row].title ?? "Empty List"
        return cell
    }
    
    
}




extension HomeViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
        let displayVc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "displayData") as! DisplayDataViewController
        displayVc.index1 = indexPath.row
        displayVc.viewDetails = taskView![indexPath.row]
        
        navigationController?.pushViewController(displayVc, animated: true)
    }
    
}
```

**AddNotesViewController:**

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

protocol RefreshDelegate {
    func loadData()
}

class AddNotesViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var titleTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var notesTextView: UITextView!
    
    let realm = try! Realm()
    
    var delegate: RefreshDelegate?
    
    var EditView : Data?
    var index2: Int?
    
    var flagAdd: Int?
    var flagEdit: Int?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if flagEdit == 1 {
            navigationItem.title = "Edit Page"
            if let myEdit = self.EditView {
                titleTextField.text = myEdit.title
                notesTextView.text = myEdit.notes
            }
        }
    }
        
        
        
        @IBAction func doneButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
            let note = notesTextView.text
            
            if titleTextField.text == ""
            {
                titleTextField.placeholder = "Write Something.."
            }
            
            else if note == "" || note == "Write notes here...." || note == "Sorry! Write Something here."
            {
                notesTextView.text = "Sorry! Write Something here."
            }
            
            else if flagAdd == 0
            {
                let titleText = titleTextField.text
                let notesField = notesTextView.text
                
                let dataRealm = Data()
                dataRealm.title = titleText!
                dataRealm.notes = notesField!
                
                try! realm.write{
                    realm.add(dataRealm)
                }
                delegate?.loadData()
                titleTextField.endEditing(true)
                notesTextView.endEditing(true)
                
                navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            }
            
            else
            {
                let newData = realm.objects(Data.self)[index2!]
                
                try! realm.write {
                    newData.title = titleTextField.text!
                    newData.notes = notesTextView.text
                }
                
                delegate?.loadData()
                
                titleTextField.endEditing(true)
                notesTextView.endEditing(true)
                
                navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
                
            }
            
        }
        
        
    }
```

The same add page is used as an edit page. That's why I used the flagAdd/flagEdit variable.

**DisplayDataViewController:**

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class DisplayDataViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var DisplayTitleField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var DisplayNotesField: UITextView!
    
    let realm = try! Realm()

    var index1 : Int?
    var viewDetails : Data?
    
    var delegate : RefreshDelegate?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if let myView = self.viewDetails {
            DisplayTitleField.text = myView.title
            DisplayNotesField.text = myView.notes
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func EditButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let editVc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "goToAdd") as! AddNotesViewController
        editVc.index2 = index1
        editVc.EditView = viewDetails
        editVc.flagEdit = 1
        
        navigationController?.pushViewController(editVc, animated: true)
    }
    
    
    
    @IBAction func deleteButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        
        try! realm.write {
            realm.delete(viewDetails!)
        }
        
        delegate?.loadData()
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HomeViewController**,
What I did is just add one line of code in `didSelectRowAt`. Here is the updated `didSelectRowAt` :

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
        let dv = (storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "displayData"))! as! DisplayDataViewController
        
        dv.index1 = indexPath.row
        dv.viewDetails = taskView![indexPath.row]

        dv.delegate = self // Newly added code.It solves a problem for deletion.

        navigationController?.pushViewController(dv, animated: true)
}
```

**DisplayDataViewController** , Here also I added `ev.delegate = delegate`. Here is the updated code for `EditButtonPressed`

```swift
@IBAction func EditButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let ev = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "goToAdd") as! AddNotesViewController
        ev.EditView = viewDetails
        ev.index2 = index1!
        ev.flagEdit = 1

        ev.delegate = delegate // Newly added code.It solves a problem for updating.
        
        navigationController?.pushViewController(ev, animated: true)    
    }
```

Finally it's working.